# Unable to serve static content from spring boot 3 and Jersey

Tags: spring-boot, static, jersey, jax-rs

I am unable to get my Spring Boot 3.0.2 app (deployed to external Tomcat) to serve static content.

I place an html file in src/main/webapp and then try to access it via localhost:8080/{{filename}}.html and get a 404.

I have my JerseyConfig set

```
property(ServletProperties.FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404, true);
```

and in application.properties I have

```
spring.jersey.type=filter
```

This is what's suggested in most answers to similar questions. However, this doesn't change anything.

Pom file has

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
<dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            </dependency>
```

EDIT:
It seems that I am only unable to see the static content on external Tomcat. When I run the app from my IDE, I am able to access the static content. What might be the difference?

Answer (score 0):

spring-boot-starter-jersey is not enough to serve statics files. spring-boot-starter-web can do it, you already included this dependency. By default spring-boot-starter-web doesn't src/main/webapp :

```
/META-INF/resources/  
/resources/  
/static/  
/public/
```

ref: https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/

You can move your static files to this directories or configure static locations :

```
spring.web.resources.static-locations=classpath:/webapp
```

Comment: I don't think that this is the issue, as I am able to access the file if I add a context. Unfortunately that isn't something that I can actually do for this app.